# Converting typescript object to valid JSON

Tags: json, angular

EDIT3: 
This is my result
[image]

This is my code that gets that result from the backend:

```
private extractTrains(res: Response){
      let body = res.json();
      let trains = body['List of vehicles'];
      return trains;
  }
```

How do I get each result element (so like trains[5]['Latitude'] is valid) instead of each result element (like trains[5][7] returns a char, not what I want?)

Another Edit:
[image]
As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43959884/1144431 now I have regular strings as each element of the array, with double quotes in the string. Now I have to convert those double quotes to single quotes for JSON, right?

Comment: See edit for some more clarification.

Comment: So, are you getting each `object` as *string*, then? Is that the problem? If so, you must parse them... `JSON.parse(obj)`.

Comment: Could you just paste the JSON you are receiving (or what you are receiving) Seems it's JSON though, when you are using `res.json()`. I'm getting confused here about how your data actually looks like initially :P, so it would help if you'd just show that :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Pengyy's answer, generally when I do stuff like this I implement a MyClass.fromJson(res) method which parses the body into a MyClass object which is easily used inside of templates and Api Services.

Think of something like this

```
export class Train {
    TripID:number;
    Direction:number;
    time:number;
    etc...

    static fromJson(json: any): Train {
        return Object.assign(this.placeholder(), json)
    }

    public static placeholder(): Train {
        let p = new Train();
        p.TripID = -1;
        p.Direction = -1;
        p.time = -1;
        etc...
        return p;
    }
}
```

Where you would then have an `Array<Train>` which gets passed to the *ngFor and can use dot notation.

So in your case you could do ( Given that the res contains an `[array]` of train jsons )

```
private extractTrains(res: Response): Array<Train> {
  return res.json().map(json => Train.fromJson(json));
}
```

---

---

Your comment clarified that it's just a parsing error, so here would be how you could reformat your JSON to parse correctly.

```
var weirdlyFormattedJson = '"{\'hello\':\'world\'}"'
var fixed = weirdlyFormattedJson.split('')
    .filter(x => {return x!='"'})
    .map(x => {return (x=="'") ? '"' : x}).join("");
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(fixed);
```

Note that this will fail if there is actually a `"` inside of a json property somewhere. Your best bet might be to remove the first and last character from each item, if that's the case you can just do this

```
var fixedJson = badJson.slice(1, -1).split('')
    .map(x => {return (x=="'") ? '"' : x}).join("");
```

Note, that this will also fail if there's a `'` inside of a property.
You might actually have to make a converter which tracks where the `:`s are and only replace the `'`s that wrap each individual key and value.

Here's a small demonstration of that, though you will have to use recursion for a real implementation 
https://jsfiddle.net/b60Ladbr/
The reason is that any nested object `{}` will not be parsed correctly, so if you encounter a `{` as the first character of a the second array item of each `:` separated array, you'll have to pull everything from `{` to `}` and pass it back into `fixJson`

Comment: Does that help me get rid of the double quotes? I feel like I need to re ask this question. body['List of vehicles'] is an array of n trains, but each element is a double quoted dtring. I have no idea how to JSONify that.

Comment: I think we were all trying to help you with something you didn't need help with :D I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Is that a quote that encapsulates the whole string?
Like `-> ""foo":"bar"" <-`?

Comment: Also I agree with AJT_82's comment on your original post, it's odd that res.json() is returning the json formatted that way. It might be indicative of a larger issue.

Comment: Shai: Yes. A string with double quotes with double quotes in it.It originally has to do with the nature of hte data being received from the Flask backend. Flask doesn't like plain old lists being sent, so I had to JSONify it.